# Get default font height for win32 DrawText()

Tags: c, windows, winapi, gdi

How can I get the default font height for the font DrawText() uses? I would rather not set a new font if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call [`GetTextMetrics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144941%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

You can use [GetTextExtentPoint32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144938%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Certainly a possibility. GetTextExtentPoint32 gives the height and width of a specific string. That may or may not be what OP wants.

Comment: @David: true, but isn't the height going to be dependent on the actual characters being rendered?

Comment: It all depends on what OP is going to do with the information. There are cases where you use text extend and other cases where you use text metrics. If you want to an absolute upper bound on the height that text could have, then text metrics are what you need. If you are writing a word wrap algorithm then you would use extend. The OP said "default font height" which made me suspect he/she wanted something that was invariant of the actual text.

Comment: I've given you an up-vote as it happens - I'm not trying to criticise, just to clarify. I also considered answering with text extent.